# To show that $f (x) = | \cos x | + |\sin x |$ is not one one and onto and not differentiable

Tags: calculus, functions

Let $f : \mathbb{R} \longrightarrow [0,2]$ be defined by $f (x) = | \cos x | + |\sin x |$. I need to show that $f$ is not one one and onto. I have only intuitive idea that $\cos x$ is even function so image of $x$ and $-x$ are same. Not one to one , but how do I properly check for other things. Hints ? Thanks

Comment: To check onto, one needs to specify the codomain.

Comment: @coffeemath sorryit was a typo , edited

Comment: Looks like the actual range is $[1,\sqrt{2}].$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(i) $f(0) = f(2\pi) = f(4\pi) = \cdots \Rightarrow$ not one to one.

(ii) Can we find $x \in \mathbb{R}$ so that $f(x) = 0 \in \operatorname{codom}f$, i.e. does $\left| \cos x \right| + \left| \sin x \right| =0$ have any real solutions?

(iii) Does $ f'(0) =\displaystyle \lim_{x \to 0} \dfrac{|\cos x| + |\sin x| - |\cos 0|-|\sin 0|}{x-0}=\lim_{x \to 0} \dfrac{|\cos x| + |\sin x| - 1}{x}$ exist?

**Edit:**

We have

$$
\lim_{x \to 0^-} \dfrac{|\cos x| + |\sin x| - 1}{x}
= \lim_{x \to 0^-} \dfrac{\cos x - \sin x - 1}{x}
\stackrel{\mathcal{L}}{=} \lim_{x \to 0^-} -\sin x - \cos\ x 
= -1.
$$

But,

$$
\lim_{x \to 0^+} \dfrac{|\cos x| + |\sin x| - 1}{x}
= \lim_{x \to 0^+} \dfrac{\cos x + \sin x - 1}{x}
\stackrel{\mathcal{L}}{=} \lim_{x \to 0^+} -\sin x + \cos\ x 
= 1.
$$

Therefore,

$$
\lim_{x \to 0} \dfrac{|\cos x| + |\sin x| - |\cos 0|-|\sin 0|}{x-0}
$$

does not exist. Hence, $f$ is not differentiable on its entire domain.

Comment: Can you please explain how limit doesnot exists

Comment: I will edit my answer for you shortly. Hang on ...

Answer (score 3):

hints:

1) Both $\sin$ and $\cos $ share the same period. Use that to show the function is not one to one.

2) Each of $\sin $ and $\cos$ is bounded between $-1$ and $1$. Use that to show that the function is not onto by showing it is bounded between $0$ and $2$ (assuming you take as the codomain $\mathbb R$, otherwise, the question has no meaning). It appears you edited the question so the domain is now $[0,2]$. So, now to show the function is not onto, show that $0$ is never attained by remembering basic facts about the trigonometric functions.

3) Apply the limit definition of the derivative at $0$, and show the limit does not exist. Alternatively, if the function was differentiable at $0$, then in a small enough neighborhood of $0$ the function $f(x)-\cos x$ would also be differentiable (as the difference of differentiable functions). However, that function is $|\sin x|$, and you can show that function is not differentiable at $0$ by applying the definition again.

Comment: The sum of two functions each bounded between $-1$ and $1$ is not necessarily between those bounds.

Comment: slip of the copy paste... thanks @coffeemath

Comment: Ittay -- did you notice the OP has inserted the codomain $[0,2]$ into the question (it wasn't there before...)

Answer (score 2):

To see it isn't onto $[0,2]$, you only need show it is never $0$. Note that $|a|+|b|=0$ iff $a=b=0.$ For your function, this means are there any $x$ for which both $\cos x=0$ and simultaneously $\sin x=0.$ It's easy to see not, just noting that e.g. $\sin x=0$ iff $x=n \pi,$ and at those points $\cos x = \pm 1.$

Added note: The function can be viewed as the "taxicab" distance between the point $(\cos x, \sin x)$ on the unit circle to the origin $(0,0).$ In this way it seems almost clear that the minimum is $1$ and the maximum is $\sqrt{2}$ attained respectively in quadrant I when $x=0$ and when $x=\pi/4.$ [By symmetry one can restrict to quadrant I, where each of the cosine and sine are nonnegative, so the absolute value signs may be dropped and usual calc methods used for max and min.]

Answer (score 1):

HINT: 1. $1-1$: It is periodic, but not constant. 2. (differentiability) What are one-sided derivatives at 0? 3. (not onto) $\sin^2x+\cos^2x=1$.

Comment: Thanks for answer , can you please explain more

Comment: @SophieClad 3) is simple. If 2 belongs to codomain $|\sin x_0|=1=|\cos x_0|$ for some $x_0$. 1) is periodic as sum of two periodic function and it is remain to check that ot attins two different values. 2) And differentiablility form definition.

Comment: Ok i see why it is not onto , butfor one one is my reasoning correct as i have stated in question

Comment: @SophieClad Your argument with $\cos$ is unsufficient, at least near zero, because  there chages of $\sin$ dominate. However it is a good intuition to find two values "far"  from 0.

Comment: I am not able to prove differentiability still

Comment: @SophieClad You know, that for small positive $x$ your function is $\cos x+\sin x$ and $f'_+(0)=sin(0)+\cos 0=1$, but for small negative $x$ we have $f(x)=\cos x-\sin x$ and $f'_-(0)=-1$.

Answer (score 1):

Here I plot the graph of your function in $x\in[-6\pi,6\pi].$ This is not an answer. But you can get a clear idea than intuition. 
[image]

Answer (score 0):

hint: $f$ is $2\pi$-periodic so you only need to worry about on $[0, 2\pi]$.  you can write out expressions for both $f$ and its derivative on the four pieces $[0,\pi/2], [\pi/2, \pi],[\pi, 3\pi/2]$ and $3\pi/2, 2pi].$ in each of these interval $f = \pm \sin x \pm \cos x$ check the derivative at the boundaries $0, \pi/2,\pi, 3\pi/2$ u